# Update 9.3.x minor verison of postgres on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, apt

What do I need to do to update Postgres to a new minor version? i.e. 9.3.1 to 9.3.2? All the documentation gives is stop the server and install the new binaries. I need more detailed information on the steps needed to upgrade via apt-get. Unless apt doesn't perform upgrades?

Note: I installed Postgres via instructions at http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Note 2: I used the [shell script](http://anonscm.debian.org/loggerhead/pkg-postgresql/postgresql-common/trunk/download/head:/apt.postgresql.org.s-20130224224205-px3qyst90b3xp8zj-1/apt.postgresql.org.sh) provided on the above url to install the postgres apt repo.

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.3
```

Comment: How exaclty did you installed it? `sudo apt-get install postgres`?

Comment: sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions you are looking at are for from-source installations.  When using APT, just run `apt-get dist-upgrade` and everything will be taken care of for you.  Note that this will restart the PostgreSQL server, so don't do it when you can't have downtime.

Comment: What is the reason for "dist-upgrade" instead of "upgrade"? Does "dist-upgrade" update all packages that need to be updated? Can I specify just postgres be upgraded?

Comment: You can use any package upgrade method you want; this was just an example.  If you just want to upgrade the PostgreSQL packages, try something like `apt-get install postgresql-9.3`.